# Visual Studio Code, terminal launcher Ctrl+Shift+` starts an xterm instead of bash in

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am not sure why  Ctrl+Shift+` and running compile tasks starts an xterm. It used to work fine and I am not sure what changed. Instead of bash it launches xterm.

I get the following error on the console:

> Executing task: cd ~/dev/build; make install <

/bin/xterm: ambiguous option "-cr" vs "-cc"

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

my terminal configuration:

```
"terminal.external.linuxExec": "bash",
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/bin/bash",
"git.ignoreLegacyWarning": true,
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "bash",
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleted all .vscode directories and started from scratch. I am sure there is a simpler solution. But this worked form.